# Javascript code optimization for Find()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have c# code that runs a query in SQL and returns roughly 2000 rows. Then a Treeview control is created and added the my main page. This is done almost instantly, which is good.

```
var orgId = $('select[name="ctl00$PageContent$FunctionsDropDownList"] option:selected').val();
        if (!orgId) {
            return false;
        }
        //calls serverside get data
        //This line happens quickly
        $('#ctl00_PageContent_HiddenRulesDialogTriggerButton').click();

        //This part takes about 10-15 minutes to finally get to the true
        var i = setInterval(function () {
            if ($('#ctl00_PageContent_treeview').find('table').length > 0)
            {
                clearInterval(i);
                StartDialog();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

So it takes about 10-15 minutes to hit the `clearInterval(i)`. When it does, `i = 978`. Not sure why it would take so long. Possibly the `find()` is really slow. Does anyone recommend an alternative?

**EDIT**

[image: Version of Internet Explorer]

Comment: Polling is not the correct way to do this.  Presumably when you call the server to get data, you are using `$.ajax()`.  Your callback will be called when the data arrives.  Probably this callback is already in your code and is being used to populate the Treeview control.  You just need to add additional code after the TreeView is populated to display your dialog.

Comment: How do you create the treeview? Don't you can attach this 'StartDialog' as a callback when the 'treeview creation action' is finished?

Comment: I didn't write the Javascript code, but I'm stuck trying to fix it. The treeview is created in code behind. Then StartDialog() creates the popup and add the treeview html. But StartDialog() isn't the problem. The bottleneck is occuring in the find()

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the fact that you are calling setInterval without the second argument (time interval)

Let's look at what your code seems to do.

1. Query the backend, pull the data needed to build the treeview. This is done fast.
2. Build the tree asynchronyously.
3. While the tree is building, keep checking it with find() to see whether it is ready.

A couple problems.

1. All DOM queries are rather slow compared to non-DOM data manipulation. So yes, find() isn't the fastest function as it it searches the entire DOM starting with the parent object you specify and returns the objects it finds.
2. If you run setInterval with just one argument like you do:

Code:

```
var timer_id = setInterval(function() {
    ...code here...
});
```

...I think it executes every millisecond. I've tested this with this code:

```
var k = 1;
var i = setInterval(function () {
    if (k < 100)
    {
        k += 1;
    } else {
        clearInterval(i);
        window.alert('Finished!');
    }
//No second argument
});
```

...and it finished almost instantly.

So I'm guessing it is going so slow because the program is firing a costly DOM search hundreds of times per second. The solutions are:

1. Provide the function that does whatever you need at the end of tree building as a callback to the asynchronous building function. This way you eliminate the need to check.
2. Try to supply a time interval to setInterval and see if it solves your issue by freeing up the program to build the tree instead of repeated checks:

Code:

```
var i = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#ctl00_PageContent_treeview').find('table').length > 0)
    {
        clearInterval(i);
        StartDialog();
        return false;
    }
//Once per second
},1000);
```

A callback would be better practice but supplying the time interval will probably work too.

Comment: I tried it at even 5000 ms, but the overall issue is IE. I ran that code, with the interval set to 5000, and it took forever. As soon as I ran it in Firefox, it took roughly 2-3 seconds to display.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.one()` , `DOMNodeInserted` event , delegating event to `document` .

```js
function StartDialog(el) {
  console.log(el)
}

$(document)
.one("DOMNodeInserted"
, "#ctl00_PageContent_treeview table"
, function(e) {
    StartDialog(this)
});

$("#ctl00_PageContent_treeview").append("<table></table>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="ctl00_PageContent_treeview"></div>
```