# Getting value from checkbox that is dynamically created

Tags: jquery

So, I am trying to get the collection of `checkboxes` that are checked in a `Div` and that are created dynamically. Essentially, I don't know the ids and I just need to loop through the ones that are checked.

I'm a .NET dev trying to iron out some `JQuery` issues :S

Care to help?

The parent div is called #`ruleWindow`. And my idea is to loop through them as such:

```js
$('#ruleWindow p.selected').each(function () {
    var p = $(this);
    ...
});
```

At first, the `Treeview` with `checkboxes` was created in `JQuery`, but because IE is a pain, I'm creating the `Treeview` in C# and handling input in `JQuery`. The `Treeview` creates `Divs`, with tables with an `input` tag.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but is this the selector you're looking for? `$('#ruleWindow p input:checked').each(function(){ ... })`

Comment: See the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector.

Comment: I am an engineer on the IE/Edge team, and would love to know what issue(s) you were facing with jQuery and IE. I'd love for you to open another question, if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: @Sampson Would you prefer to do this on another platform?

Comment: @NerdinTraining Our team uses Stack Overflow to document web platform issues, as well as provide work-arounds. If you know of a jQuery issue in any version of IE, we would love to have it documented here, along with community suggestions for alternative approaches.

Comment: @Sampson How do I include you in the question?

Comment: I'll check [your recently-asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a674896%20is%3aquestion).

Comment: @Sampson before I do that, this was the original question. I never awarded an answer because I couldn't get it to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068960/javascript-code-optimization-for-find

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101128/discussion-between-nerd-in-training-and-sampson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it thanks to [Joseph Marikle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph-marikle@joseph), except I had to remove the p from the identifier.

```
$('#ruleWindow input:checked').each(function () {
            var p = $(this);
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also have some sort of submit button, you can tie the click handler of the button to loop through the checkboxes in `ruleWindow` that are checked.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $('#ruleWindow').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(d, e) {
        console.log($(e).val());
        console.log($(e).attr('id'));
  }); 
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dumexutoqo/edit?html,js,console,output) example